# How to update the rows that are not identical in terms of data in a tableB from tableA given that table structure are same in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, rdbms

Basically I've two tables with almost 46 columns now I wanted some PL/SQL script that can update the row if found unequal from a source table A to table B ( which needs to be updated) there is one primary key on the basis of which comparison will take place and after that update if found unequal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the MERGE I have came to the correct answer which is satisfying the requirements as mentioned in my question.

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A 
USING 
(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
) T 
ON 
(
    TABLE_A.PK=TABLE_B.PK
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET TABLE_A.COL1 = T.COL1,
        ...
        TABLE_A COL46 = T.COL46;
```

Comment: You almost copy pasted my answer :)

Comment: @Hawk yes thats where the inspiration came :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

Assuming you need to update all columns if the PK does not match, then this is a general syntax:

```
MERGE INTO table_b
USING 
(
  SELECT column1, ... column48
  FROM table_a
) a ON (b.pk = a.pk)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET a.column1 = b.column1,
        .....
        a.column46 = b.column46;
```

Comment: By above solution I am getting the following error -
`ORA-00905: missing keyword `

Comment: @Bharat would you please post your code, or part of it

Comment: actually comparision PK is also one of the column let say ID, we are matching on that basis and updating other columns.